# printing repeated parts of file with awk

Tags: awk, tex

I would like to go through this file:

```
\chapter{CHAPTER}

TEXT   
\e
h454
\e    
\e
454
\e    
\begin{figure}
\NOTE{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{f.pdf}
\caption{\NOTEB{The concept}}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

SOME TEXT    
\e
454
\e    
SOME TEXT

\begin{figure}
\NOTE{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{f.pdf}
\caption{\NOTEB{The concept}}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\chapter{CHAPTER}

SOME TEXT
```

and print some parts:

```
awk '/\\begin\{figure\}/,/\\end\{figure\}/' file.tex
awk '/\\e/,/\\e/' file.tex
awk '/\chapter/' file.tex
```

but all into one file and in the order as in the input file. So, the desired output is (empty line does't matter):

```
\chapter{CHAPTER}  
\e
h454
\e
\e
454
\e
\begin{figure}
\NOTE{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{f.pdf}
\caption{\NOTEB{The concept}}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}    
\e
454
\e    
\begin{figure}
\NOTE{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{f.pdf}
\caption{\NOTEB{The concept}}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\chapter{CHAPTER}
```

How to connect these commands and make it to follow the order of input file?

Comment: I suggest to use `sed` for this job. You're already using its syntax.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How to use sed please for it. I write only separated commands I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/\\label/{
  next
}
/\\begin\{figure\}|\\beq/{
  found=1
}
found;
/\\end\{figure\}|\\eeq/{
  found=""
}
/chapter/
' Input_file
```

Since I have written this on my cell I haven't tested it, please feel free to comment on any suggestions.

Comment: How to remove lines starting \label from the file? I tried to write in the end: `| '!/^\\label/'` (I mean that I edit your last line as `'| '!/^\\label/' Input_file`)

Comment: @Archie, please try my edit now and lemme know if this helps?